# CI Bonfire: Can't proceed from first step in installation

Tags: codeigniter, installation, bonfire

I plan to use [Bonfire 0.7](http://cibonfire.com/) in my new project but I can't get to install it. I've downloaded the master package and unzipped it into the `www` folder of my Wamp Server. The landing page tells me to manually create database and set the config files. I've done it as required but when I click the continue button it redirects me to `http://localhost/public` which obviously gives the error `The requested URL /public/ was not found on this server.`

Is this an `.htaccess` problem? The site documentation says *The web root should point to the /public folder.* How should I do that? I know I'm doing something terribly wrong for which there might be a simple obvious explanation but what? Please help!

**Edit:** When I manually go to `http://localhost/bonfire/public` it redirects me to `http://localhost/bonfire/index.php/install` which is the same page as the landing page where clicking on *continue* button again redirects to `http://localhost/public`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of head-banging I finally solved it by installing Bonfire on XAMPP instead of WAMP and is now working like a charm. Don't know if this counts as a solution at all but whatever. I don't know what kind of grudge Bonfire has with WAMP.

Comment: I have Windows 8.1 Pro 64bit Laptop. I want to install `Ci-bonfire` can you please advise me what is the best way. I tried lot of articles. But wont work. Can you explain it from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Ali your application is in the bonfire subfolder on the root. Move all the files inside the `bonfire` folder to the `www` folder. [Installation document](http://cibonfire.com/docs/developer/installation) on cibonfire website has the details.

Note: by moving the bonfire application to the root `www`, you won't be able to run other web applications. It is better to keep applications in subfolders on WAMP. If this is what you decide, change the `config.php` (/application/config/) and `.htaccess`accordingly. The bonfire [forum](http://forums.cibonfire.com/discussion/1882/remove-url-using-htaccess/p1) has details.

Comment: Still not working. The `continue` button now redirects to `localhost/bonfire/index.php/install` and the page says `404 Not Found`. I have also enabled and disabled `mod_rewrite` and changed `$config[index_page]` in config.php, but in either case not working.

Comment: There is no `install` folder anywhere in the package.

Comment: Ali, after installing Bonfire, copy all the files from the Public folder to the root (in your case localhost/bonfire/). Now follow the instructions in the bonfire [forum post](http://forums.cibonfire.com/discussion/1882/remove-url-using-htaccess/p1).

Comment: @GlänzendePerlen can you please explain me how did you install bonfire in Xampp

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. It works for me.

Edit the `index.php` file under `bonfire-master` folder.

Add the sub folder path `index.php` file like this

```
$install_url = 'http'.((empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) or $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'off')?'':'s')  .'://'. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] .'/{sub folder name}/public/';
```

Replace the sub folder name with your sub folder.

Then rename `1.htaccess` to `.htaccess` file under public folder and search for `Rewrite Base`

Add the sub folder path there .

That should fix the issue.